# memory allocation failure during map/unordered_map insertion

Tags: c++, exception, out-of-memory, new-operator

I am unable to capture a failure to allocate memory when inserting into a map, which results in a crash due to a segmentation fault.

```
struct Data
{
    int64_t arr[100000000000000000]; // Large data to cause allocation failure
};

typedef unordered_map<int64_t, Data> UOM;

int main()
{
    //void* p = malloc(sizeof(int64_t)*100000000000000000);
    //void* p = new int64_t [100000000000000000];
    //cout <<p <<endl;
    
    UOM m;
    try
    {
        m[1];
    } catch(...)
    {
    }
}
```

If we used malloc it would return a NULL whereas new throws std::bad_alloc which can be caught. However, the insert into map which would need to allocate this memory just crashes (with a segmentation fault).

why is this the case and what should be behaviour as per standards?

EDIT: The platform, compiler are: Old compiler g++ 4.7.1 with "-std=c++11" flag on Redhat 6.10. Yeah we live in stone age!

Comment: why is this the case of what?

Comment: that the memory allocation error cant be caught. Note that allocation failure of the same can be caught if we directly new/malloc.

Comment: I'm able to catch the `std::bad_alloc` (which is being thrown) on my machine.

Comment: Works for me https://godbolt.org/z/q1dbrq

Comment: i think that you are only seeing a log message, but the exception is been captured correctly

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to create the `m` object (and thus causing a `bad_alloc` error) outside of your `try ... catch` block. Move the `try` 'back' one level and you'll catch the exception:

```cpp
int main()
{
    try {
        UOM m;
        m[1];
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Caught!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Note also that the following catches the exception *at creation* (with **clang-cl**, full optimization):

```cpp
int main()
{
    UOM* m;
    try {
        m = new UOM;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Caught at creation!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    try {
        (*m)[1];
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Caught at insertion!" << std::endl;
    }
    delete m;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT #2: This is possibly implementation-defined behaviour for the default constructor of `std::unordered_map`, as indicated on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map):

> (1) Constructs empty container. Sets max_load_factor() to 1.0. For the
> default constructor, the number of buckets is implementation-defined.

Comment: i don't think this changes anything, the error is occurring on `m[1];`, if you run this code with `UOM m;` up one line, nothing changes

Comment: @Berto99 Probably compiler optimization - merging the declaration with the insertion.

Comment: That would be an invalid "optimisation", as it changes the observable result of the program

Comment: @Caleth I agree - I'm just 'thinking aloud' really. See edit.

Comment: I'm not sure why the buckets require actual allocation of data, and why would there be a segfault on escaped exception (correct me if this a normal behaviour). Would be great if you could reproduce it in an online compiler. I tried gcc9 and clang10 on Wandbox, but it only threw at insertion.

Comment: @AdrianMole this does not change anything as mentioned by Berto99. m[1] is just an example - in practise this would usually happen much later when the process is running out of the required contigous memory.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get this into an online compiler -  but I'm not too familiar with such beasts. I've tried (locally) with MSVC, but that won't even compile the code: **error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes**.

Comment: @Binu Can you tell us which compiler/platform you are using? It is very difficult to 'emulate' **clang-cl** online, as it uses the "clang" front-end but (I believe) the MSVC 'implementation' files.

Comment: @AdrianMole apologies should be part of qn(will edit) - it is an old compiler g++ 4.7.1 on Redhat 6.10.